# How can I ensure that these reports are appearing or can be seen on SQL Server Reporting Services(SSRS) URL?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am new to SSRS. I have developed some reports using BIDS  using SQL Server Reporting Services(SSRS) when I run them from my machine reports are running ok. But there are not appearing from SQL Server Reporting Services(SSRS). Even when I open SQL Server Reporting Services(SSRS) in a web broswer
I can not see the reports  on SSRS. How can I ensure that these reports are appearing or can be seen on SQL Server Reporting Services(SSRS) URL?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you deployed them?

Right-Click on the report and go to `Deploy`

or

In the `Build` menu select "Deploy *projectname*"

You may have to set the project properties first for `TargetServerURL` to something like

http://*SSRSserver*/reportserver

They can be found in the `Project` menu under "*projectname* Properties"

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to deploy your reports on server -

1] You can directly deploy it from your VS by right clicking on your report & selecting deploy option, here you need to mention target server -

```
http://[server name]/ReportServer
```

2] If you are able to access report server then web browser provide one option to upload your reports. So you can upload your report directly on report server (.rdl file). Here you need to set proper connnection string & permission rights to access the report.

Hope this will help you..!!